# Why ARP requests a non-local address?

Tags: linux, tcp, arp

I have a Linux virtual server with 2 NICs.

```
eth0 <IP1>
eth1 <IP2>
```

`arp_filter` is turned on and `rp_filter` is set to be 2(loose mode).
Policy-routing is configured as the following:

```
table T1
default via <GW> dev eth0 src <IP1>
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo
<LAN> dev eth0 src <IP1>

table T2
default via <GW> dev eth1 src <IP2>
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo
<LAN> dev eth1 src <IP2>

ip rule add from <IP1> table T1
ip rule add from <IP2> table T2
```

After that, I can `ping` both binding floatingips of `<IP1>` and `<IP2>` from outside. However `ping -I eth1 <some_domain>` dosen't work. `tcpdump` shows that when I ping from `eth1` to outside, Linux directly asks `MAC` of the outside address, which is incorrect because they are not in the same `LAN`.

Here is `tcpdump` data:

```
root@rm-2:~# tcpdump -i eth1 arp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol     decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535     bytes
17:53:08.696191 ARP, Request who-has 172.30.250.119 tell 172.30.248.2, length 46
17:53:08.728482 ARP, Request who-has 172.30.251.144 tell 172.30.251.138, length 46
17:53:09.447252 ARP, Request who-has 61.135.169.125 tell 172.30.251.43, length 28
17:53:09.551514 ARP, Request who-has 172.30.250.127 tell 172.30.248.2, length 46
17:53:09.698076 ARP, Request who-has 172.30.250.119 tell 172.30.248.2, length 46
17:53:09.859046 ARP, Request who-has 172.30.248.246 tell 172.30.248.245, length 46
17:53:10.446009 ARP, Request who-has 61.135.169.125 tell 172.30.251.43, length 28
17:53:10.477104 ARP, Request who-has 172.30.250.128 tell 172.30.248.2, length 46
```

As you can see, `61.135.169.125` is a foreign address, is this a bug or something?

**EDIT**
Output of `route`:  // 172.30.248.1 is the GW

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use      Iface  
default         172.30.248.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0      eth0
```

Comment: Could you give the output of `route`

Answer (score 7):

Answer:

You need to add an output interface rule (`ip rule add oif ...`) in addition to `ip rule add from ...`, because ping is binding to the **interface**, not the IP.

Example:

```
ip rule add from <IP1> table T1
ip rule add oif <eth0> table T1
ip rule add from <IP2> table T2
ip rule add oif <eth1> table T2
```

Explanation:

The ping example in your question is using the interface as the source (`ping -I eth1 <some domain>`), which does not have any matching policy routes. So ping is behaving exactly like it would if the there were no routes defined for the **interface** at all.

Example to test/prove (starting without policy routing):

Using my phone USB tethered as an alternate route, I have the following base configuration.

```
Linux desktop:
$ ip addr show usb0
...
inet 192.168.42.1/32 ...
..

Android phone:
$ ip addr show rndis0
...
inet 192.168.42.129/24 ...
...
```

Because the desktop usb0 interface is assigned a /32 address, if I try to `ping 192.168.42.129 -I 192.168.42.1`, it will fail because there is no route defined for that address, and it is not within the broadcast domain of the usb0 *address*.  However, with `ping 192.168.42.129 -I usb0` -- I am telling ping to use the **interface** itself, and there are no routes matching the interface (thus, no concept of a broadcast domain), so it will blindly trigger an ARP request for any IP that is not it's own.

Lets attempt to ping using the **interface** (no routes). This will cause an ARP request to occur even though it is not within the same broadcast domain:

```
desktop$ ping 192.168.42.129 -I usb0
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n icmp or arp
ARP, Request who-has 192.168.42.129 tell 192.168.42.1, length 28
ARP, Reply 192.168.42.129 is-at 3e:04:37:23:05:0e, length 28
IP 192.168.42.1 > 192.168.42.129: ICMP echo request, id 24641, seq 1, length 64
IP 192.168.42.129 > 192.168.42.1: ICMP echo reply, id 24641, seq 1, length 64
```

Using the source IP of the interface (no routes), it does not make an ARP request because the source is not within the broadcast domain:

```
desktop$ ping 192.168.42.129 -I 192.168.42.1
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n icmp or arp
... nothing comes over the wire, as expected ...
```

Now if I add a route to the host over the interface, ping knows it can make an ARP request for the 192.168.42.129 address:

```
desktop$ ip route add 192.168.42.129/32 dev usb0
desktop$ ping 192.168.42.129 -I 192.168.42.1
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n icmp or arp
ARP, Request who-has 192.168.42.129 tell 192.168.42.1, length 28
ARP, Reply 192.168.42.129 is-at 3e:04:37:23:05:0e, length 28
IP 192.168.42.1 > 192.168.42.129: ICMP echo request, id 24667, seq 1, length 64
IP 192.168.42.129 > 192.168.42.1: ICMP echo reply, id 24667, seq 1, length 64
```

So the same concept applies when I try to ping something off-network; if I ping 8.8.8.8 using the **interface** as the source, it will blindly make an ARP request sans any matching routes:

```
desktop$ ping 8.8.8.8 -I usb0
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n icmp or arp
ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 192.168.42.1, length 28
```

When using the interface *address*, the lack of any kind of next-hop route in the routing table will cause it to fail and not make an ARP request:

```
desktop$ ping 8.8.8.8 -I 192.168.42.1
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n icmp or arp
... nothing ...
```

So lets add policy routing for the 192.168.42.1 address (using "ip rule from ...") to use 192.168.42.129 as the next-hop default, in the same manner as your question example:

```
desktop$ sudo ip rule add from 192.168.42.1 lookup T1
desktop$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0 table T1
desktop$ ping 8.8.8.8 -I 192.168.42.1
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.42.1 : 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=28.6 ms
...
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n icmp or arp
IP 192.168.42.1 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 24969, seq 1, length 64
IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.42.1: ICMP echo reply, id 24969, seq 1, length 64
```

It works, because we are using the *address*, it rightfully matches the ip rule.

Now we try the same ping again using the **interface**:

```
desktop$ ping 8.8.8.8 -I usb0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.42.1 usb0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
...
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n icmp or arp
ARP, Request who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 192.168.42.1, length 28
```

It fails; there no **interface** route for the next-hop, so it will again make an ARP request, which will never get replied to. So we need to add an ip rule for the **interface** to use 192.168.42.129 as the next-hop as well:

```
desktop$ sudo ip rule add oif usb0 lookup T1
desktop$ ping 8.8.8.8 -I usb0
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.42.1 usb0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=10.7 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.791/10.791/10.791/0.000 ms
...
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n icmp or arp
IP 192.168.42.1 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 24979, seq 1, length 64
IP 8.8.8.8 > 192.168.42.1: ICMP echo reply, id 24979, seq 1, length 64
```

I believe generally, the lack of an interface route would not have had a negative impact on your implementation for normal, non-interface bound, outgoing connections. Most (not all) applications bind to the *address* for outbound TCP/UDP connections, and only bind to the **interface** for incoming connections (listening). The ping utility is a special case.

To prove this, if I remove the interface rule from the routing policy, I am still able to use normal outbound sockets when specifying the bind *address*. In the example below I use telnet and netcat, in both cases specifying the bind address (`-b 192.168.42.1`) and it properly matches the T1 table, and thus uses the gateway.

```
# remove the interface route, keep the address route
desktop$ sudo ip rule del from all oif usb0 lookup T1
desktop$ nc -zv 8.8.8.8 443 -s 192.168.42.1
google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8] 443 (https) open

phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n host 8.8.8.8
IP 192.168.42.1.40785 > 8.8.8.8.443: Flags [S], seq 1678217252, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 20223895 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
IP 8.8.8.8.443 > 192.168.42.1.40785: Flags [S.], seq 86178051, ack 1678217253, win 28400, options [mss 1432,sackOK,TS val 1937335284 ecr 20223895,nop,wscale 8], length 0
....
desktop$ telnet 8.8.8.8 53 -b 192.168.42.1
...
phone# tcpdump -i rndis0 -n host 8.8.8.8
IP 192.168.42.1.57109 > 8.8.8.8.53: Flags [.], ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 20288983 ecr 4154032957], length 0
IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.42.1.57109: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 1, win 111, options [nop,nop,TS val 4154033968 ecr 20288983], length 0
```

I ran into this same issue while testing a policy-route implementation, and it took me a bit wrap my head around why my interface pings were unanswered. Hopefully this clears it up.

Comment: Incredible answer! Thank you! I kept using `-I <interface>` and wondered why I was getting ICMP host unreachable messages despite having `ip rule from <ip> lookup t2` where t2 had a fully working default route.